# permutation in a list with repetition ocaml

Tags: ocaml, combinations, permutation

I have a function that makes combinations of K distinct objects chosen from the N elements of a list, the problem is doesn't permute with repetition, for example:

extract 2 ["a";"b";"c";"d"];;
- : string list list =
[["a"; "b"]; ["a"; "c"]; ["a"; "d"]; ["b"; "c"]; ["b"; "d"]; ["c"; "d"]]

Here is my code:

```
# let rec extract k list =
if k <= 0 then [ [] ]
else match list with
     | [] -> []
     | h :: tl ->
        let with_h = List.map (fun l -> h :: l) (extract (k-1) tl) in
        let without_h = extract k tl in
        with_h @ without_h;;
```

I'm trying figure out how would do that, thanks for replying.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a function that makes combinations of K distinct objects

Indeed.

> the problem is doesn't permute with repetition,

It's not much more difficult than combinations. There are two ways to go about your inductive step. If you want to permute `k` elements of a (non-empty) set `A` you can:

**Method 1**

For every element `x` in `A`, calculate the permutations of `k-1` elements of `A\{x}` and put `x` in front of all those permutations. Then join the sets of solutions you obtained for each `x`.

**Method 2**

Choose one `x` in `A`, calculate the permutations of `k-1` elements of `A\{x}`, then for each  permutation found calculate new ones by inserting `x` in each possible position.